Backtransforming standard errors from scaled variables
I use data with scaled values based on this dataset I made a model such as :
data <- data.frame(
      X1 = c(1.2, 2.3, 3.1, 4.8, 5.5, 4.6),
      X2 = c(10.4, 9.3, 8.2, 7.1, 6.0, 5.2),
      X3 = c(5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 12.0),
      rand = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
    )    
    
data = data %>% 
      mutate(across(X1:X2, ~ scale(.), .names = "scaled_{.col}"))    

model = lmerTest::lmer(X3 ~ scaled_X1 + scaled_X2 + (1|rand), data = data)
summary(model)


I want to plot the estimates given by the model, but with backtransformed values from the scale() function to plot more understandable results.
If I'm not mistaken, coefficients can be backtransformed if estimates of summary(model) are divided by their standard deviation :
XS = (X0 - mean) / sd
so if Y = BXS + A, we have Y = B((X0 - mean) / sd) + A
and Y = B / sd * X0 + (- B*mean/sd + A)
So Y is function of X0 such that Y = (B / sd) * X0
If I'm right, how do I then backtransform the values of standard error given by the model in summary(model), to plot them ?
According to this issue, this transformation doesn't make sense, but interpreting the plot for a reader would be a nightmare if I keep them scaled.

Does this or this or any of the related answers (see the "linked questions" sections from these pages) help?

Oops, that most of these are about unscaling/back-transforming coefficients. Unscaling the SEs is actually easier, you just divide by the scaling value (SD_orig). If I get a chance I will post an example.
